# CLT for a dependent sum

Tags: probability

Let $(X_1,...,X_n)$ be the uniformly distribution on the sphere of radius $\sqrt{n}$. I'm looking for a version of the central limit theorem to tell me that $1/\sqrt{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ converges to a standard normal distribution. Plotting the histogram shows it is indeed so, but the lack of independence is tricky. Any advice on how to proceed?

I know that we can write the distributions as $\sqrt{n}X^n / \|X^n\|$ then we know $1/\sqrt{n}\|X^n\|$ is approximately constant, $X^n$ here being an iid standard Gaussian vector. However, I'm more interesting in the version of the CLT that deals with the dependence that such approximations.

Comment: I don't understand the question. How exactly are the $X_i$ distributed, both by themselves (i.e. marginally) and together (i.e. jointly)? It seems like you're saying that $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$, as a vector, is uniformly distributed on the sphere of radius $\sqrt{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Am I correct?

Comment: By uniformly on the sphere, I mean distributed according to the Haar measure, aka the unique translation invariant measure on the sphere.  For a concrete form, it's often best to represent the distribution as $\sqrt{n}X^n/\|X^n\|$, where $X^n$ has iid standard normal distribution in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Aka yes you're correct.

Comment: This seems difficult. Part of the difficulty is that you aren't even in the usual *setting*: you really have variables $X_{i,n}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ and $i=1,2,\dots,n$, rather than just one sequence. The $X_{i,n}$ are identically distributed and somewhat weakly dependent for fixed $n$, and their mean and variance is constant in both variables. But the distribution changes considerably otherwise, so your situation is quite different from the classical CLT. Here is a well-defined, possibly relevant, but much smaller question: what is $E[|X_{i,n}|^3]$? Is it bounded?

Comment: Actually, if you're familiar CLT literature, the setting you mentioned is the normal setting, usually just masked. Typically, you have a triangular array $X_{n,i}$ where the $S_n$ is the sum of row n, and you want to know something about the sequence of normalized partial sums. Here, I'm thinking the martingale CLT may work, though I need a weaker condition than the one on the Wikipedia article. Also for fixed $n$, all moments exist since $X_{n,i}$ is a.s. Bounded.

Comment: It's perfectly normal if there is no explicit dependence on $n$, but here there is a strong explicit dependence on n. Also, sure, all moments exist for fixed n, but the $L^\infty$ norm is diverging as $n$ increases, so it is not so obvious that the moments of order higher than $2$ are not also diverging.

Comment: Doesn't your second paragraph answer the question of the first?